# Neo4j:Deletes relationships automatically

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I am using spring data neo4j version 4.1.2 with bolt driver 2.0.6. I am facing issue of breaking relationship between entities automatically.

I have an domain named organization and organization belongs to many entities but i am mentioning few.

**Organization schema**

```
    public class Organization {

      private String formalName;
      private String shortName;

    @Relationship(type = COUNTRY)
        private Country country;

        @Relationship(type = HAS_GROUP)
        private List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**And country schema is**

```
public class Country {

@Relationship(type = HAS_HOLIDAY)
    private List< CountryHolidayCalender> countryHolidayCalenderList;

}
```

When i am updating organization it breaks all relationship of country like breaks country-holiday relationship etc

**Organization update code**

```
Organization unit = organizationGraphRepository.findOne(unitId);
 unit.setFormalName(organizationGeneral.getFormalName());
 unit.setShortName(organizationGeneral.getShortName());
 organizationGraphRepository.save(unit);
```

I am unable to find, what i am doing wrong. Please help me, we can't afford this kind of bug at this time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying a greater depth for loading the `Organization` entity ? e.g.  `organizationGraphRepository.findOne(unitId, 2)`

Comment: I got your point, few relationships coming when i find by organization by id, then after save it only updates these relationship,rest of breaks. So if i have to update lot of relationship data, then should i write custom queries for every one or any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The default depth for loading entities is 1. Which means that `findOne(id)` will only return the given entity + its direct connected entities.
In your case `organization --> country --> CountryHolidayCalender`, only organization and related country will be loaded.

That's maybe why you are not seeing the attached nodes.

`save` tracks object states, to detect changes and optimize the updates.
There will be no database update for objects / properties that didn't change between `find` and `save`.

So, as long as you don't touch at `@Relationship` annotated attributes, you can save safely, they will not be modified even if they were not loaded.

Regarding your previous comment, there is no lazy loading in SDN for dynamic depth retrieval (existed, was deprecated). So, yes, you have to manage the depth yourself.
If your volume of data is not too big, your might want to load everything at once (with `find(id, -1)`).
Another option could be to load on-demand, manually querying missing pieces of graph.

You may also be interested in [this ticket](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/70) for finer control on entity loading.

Comment: Can you give me answer of one question,is there any chance of breaking relationship if i load graph using depth 2 and saving without any depth ?

Comment: This should be safe, your relationships should be preserved